# How can I customize the default display of FileInfo objects in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

The script below shows what happens when I try to suppress the Mode property from the output of a FileInfo. I am only interested in how to do this script wide. I do not want to have to specify my format every time I get a list of files. By my limited understanding, the second Get-Item c:\Windows\notepad.exe call should not have the Mode property. I tried to sanity check this with a Process object, but that made even less sense. I didn't look too far into the xml file stuff that predates this approach, but it looked like the Mode property wasn't even in there. I don't know where it's coming from. Thanks!

Script:

```
(Get-TypeData -TypeName System.IO.FileInfo).DefaultDisplayPropertySet.ReferencedProperties

Get-Item c:\Windows\notepad.exe | ft

Update-TypeData -Force -TypeName System.IO.FileInfo -DefaultDisplayPropertySet LastWriteTime,FileSize,Name
Update-TypeData -Force -TypeName System.IO.DirectoryInfo -DefaultDisplayPropertySet LastWriteTime,FileSize,Name
Update-TypeData -Force -TypeName System.IO.FileSystemInfo -DefaultDisplayPropertySet LastWriteTime,FileSize,Name

(Get-TypeData -TypeName System.IO.FileInfo).DefaultDisplayPropertySet.ReferencedProperties
Get-Item c:\Windows\notepad.exe | ft
```

Output:

```
Mode
LastWriteTime
FileSize
Name


    Directory: C:\Windows


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
-a---          7/9/2015  12:13 PM     221184 notepad.exe                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 


LastWriteTime
FileSize
Name


    Directory: C:\Windows


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
-a---          7/9/2015  12:13 PM     221184 notepad.exe
```

Comment: the strange thing is that using `remove-typedata system.io.fileinfo` it removes the value but not the column. I've tried to modify some *.ps1xml file in `$pshome` folder  removing all the `mode` references for `[fileinfo]` type but without success.

Comment: Theoretically, you need to create a new *.format.ps1.xml file with a view description you need, then import this view with Update-FormatData cmdlet. But it did not work for me, either. When I view the list of available format view definitions after running Update-FormatData, all I see is the duplicated list of built-in views. I couldn't make PowerShell to import my custom views. Though, it seems to be working in some cases: http://blogs.iis.net/sergeia/how-to-change-output-format-in-powershell